# Gravar arquivo de vídeo após captura no site

Tags: php, javascript, html5, html5-audio, html5-video

Tenho uma página que captura um vídeo + áudio do usuário usando HTML5 e JavaScript. O código segue:

```
<video width="600" height="400"></video>
<input type="button" id="stopbt" value="stop"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   navigator.getUserMedia = (
   navigator.getUserMedia ||
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
   navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
   navigator.msGetUserMedia);

   var video = document.querySelector('video');
      var cameraStream = '';
      if(navigator.getUserMedia){
          navigator.getUserMedia(
          {
            audio: true, 
            video: true
          },

    function(stream)
    {
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        cameraStream = stream;
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    },
    function(error)
    {
        document.writeln("Há um problema para acessar os dispositivos.")
    }
    );
}
else
{
    document.writeln("Captura não é suportada!");
}
document.querySelector('#stopbt').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(e)
    {
        video.src='';
        cameraStream.stop();
    });
</script>
```

Porém, este código apenas captura o vídeo com áudio, mas não gera um arquivo no servidor. Estou usando PHP no projeto...

Existe alguma maneira de gerar um arquivo no servidor a partir de uma captura como essa (contendo áudio e vídeo)? E, se há, é possível determinar inclusive o formato que esse arquivo será gerado (tipo um AVI)?

Comment: Também estou ansiando por uma forma de se fazer isso ;)

Comment: Você não consegue enviar o vídeo para o servidor dentro de um FormData com AJAX?

Comment: @TobyMosque, não sei como usar FormData com Ajax aplicado a este caso. Vc teria como criar algum exemplo, ou enviar algum link que possa me ajudar a entender como usar?

Comment: posso criar um exemplo de como enviar um stream para o servidor, a parte do PHP você vai ter que desenrolar, mas será a mesma coisa de enviar um arquivo em um inputFile.

Comment: Sim, a parte do PHP eu faço sem problemas. Obrigado!

Comment: @Atoyansk, pronto, fiz uma resposta com a parte client-side, infelizmente não poderei lhe ajudar com o PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou postar apenas a parte do envio do JavaScript, como você vai receber no PHP e vai processar a Stream, isto irei deixar ao seu criterio.

Para o exemplo abaixo, irei utilizar um `input:file`, nele você deve realizar o upload de um video qual quer, o importante aqui é como vamos fazer para enviar um `Blob` (a sua variavel `stream`) com um arquivo para o servidor.

No exemplo abaixo, eu chamo o `Blob` de `arquivo`.

```js
//caso não tenha um arquivo de video, baixe um exemplo em:
//http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm

var file = document.getElementById("file");
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
var exibir = document.getElementById("exibir");
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var pegarArquivo = function () {
  if (file.files.length > 0) {
    var arquivo = file.files[0];
    if (arquivo.type.indexOf("video") != -1) {
      return arquivo;
    } else {
      alert("Selecione um arquivo de video");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Selecione um arquivo");
  }
  return null;
}

exibir.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var arquivo = pegarArquivo();
  if (arquivo) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(arquivo);
    video.src = url;
  }
});

enviar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var arquivo = pegarArquivo();
  if (arquivo) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("arquivo", arquivo);        

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open("POST", "%URL com extensão PHP que espera o arquivo%", true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
      if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
          alert("arquivo rececido com sucesso");
        } else {
          alert("ocorreu um erro durante o envio");
        }
      }
    }        
    httpRequest.send(formData);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
<br />
<input id="exibir" type="button" value="Exibir Video" />
<input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar Video" />
<br />
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" loop="" autoplay="" ></video>
```

Ao usar um `FormData` você está enviando um `form` ao servidor, você pode montar um dinamicamente como no exemplo ou utilizar um form já existente, como por exemplo:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var data = new FormData(form);
...
httpRequest.send(data);
```

Então o que basicamente estamos fazendo é enviar o arquivo dentro de um `form` através de uma requisição POST.

Mas um detalhe, para enviar um `FormData`, você precisar setar o `header` `Content-Type` para `multipart/form-data`, este é o valor default caso esteja utilizando `XMLHttpRequest` para realizar a requisição `AJAX`.

Caso esteja utilizando `jQuery`, ele modifica esta propriedade, então terá de informar a ele para usar a forma convencional e não realizar modificações:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("arquivo", arquivo)

$.ajax({
    url: "%URL com extensão PHP que espera o arquivo%",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        alert("arquivo rececido com sucesso");
    }
});
```

lembrando que você precisa enviar um `multipart/form-data`, caso envie como `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (uma string similar a uma `queryString`), você não conseguirá enviar um arquivo ao servidor, então o seu método PHP deve está preparado para receber neste formato (que inclusive é o padrão adotado pela web atualmente).

Comment: Para entender melhor: no meu caso, como não há envio de arquivo por input file, mas sim uma captura (armazenada na variável `stream`) o que eu usaria na prática seria algo como a sua função `enviar`, substituindo a variável `arquivo` por `stream`. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Correto, você vai adicionar a Stream ao FormData da mesma forma que fiz com o Arquivo.